# Multiplicative identity in a monoid ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, monoid

Let $R$ be a ring and $S$ a subset of $R$.

I want to prove that $1:S\rightarrow R: s \mapsto 1_R$ is the multiplicative identity in the ring $(R^{(s)},*,+,1,0)$ (with $R^{(S)}$ the subset of $R^S$ with functions of finite support). $*$ is defined as follows: 
$$ f*g:S \rightarrow: s\mapsto \sum_{a,b\in S; a*b=s}f(a)*g(b)$$.

This is what I have :

$$(f*1)(s) 
= \sum_{a,b\in S; a*b=s} f(a)*1(b) 
= \sum_{a,b\in S; a*b=s} f(a)*1_R
= \sum_{a,b\in S; a*b=s} f(a)
=\sum_{r \in f(S)} r
\neq f(s)$$

Does somebody see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Also, you are assuming $S$ is a monoid, right?)

> Does somebody see where I went wrong?

It happened in this line:

> I want to prove that $1:S\rightarrow R: s \mapsto 1_R$ is the multiplicative identity in the ring $(R^{(s)},*,+,1,0)$

The function $s\mapsto 1_R$ does not have finite support if $S$ is infinite, so it is clearly not even a candidate to be the identity.

You'll have better luck proving that the map sending $s\mapsto 0_R$ if $s\neq 1_S$ and $1_S\mapsto 1_R$ is the identity of the monoid ring $R^{(S)}$.

Comment: Thank you! ($S$ is indeed a monoid).